# UI kitten Button custom mapping not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ui-kitten

I'm trying to remove the margin horizontal that is applied to the button text but I'm unable to remove it
and also when I change the category it is not getting applied, can someone provide me with a an example on how to remove the button text margin (using custom mapping)

Here is the code for the category also

```
   <Button
      status="primary"
      size="tiny"
      appearance="ghost">
      {(props) => (
        <Text {...props} category="p1">
          Edit
        </Text>
      )}
    </Button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you mean this?

```
<Button
  status="primary"
  size="tiny"
  appearance='ghost'
  style={{width: 0}}
>
  {(props) => (
    <Text {...props} category="p1">
      Edit
    </Text>
  )}
</Button>
```

[Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@maltoze/db1af3)

Comment: I was having a problem trying to apply a custom font on the button and this helped me. Thank you!

Comment: Yes something like this, do you know a way to edit the text via custom mapping for ghost (appearance).
Something more specific.